# Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i am new in Ionic. I added android platform in my ionic application and tried to run the application in real android device but i am getting following error in my command prompt i am using windows 10 machine on my end.

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

following are my environment variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

Please suggest

Comment: Did you try ti do what the error says? Download the latest android SDK?

Comment: yes i downloaded from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: what is inside C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk  all the version are downloaded ?  and also Try to change environment variable like    ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update android sdk,

First you update your android sdk atleast API LEVEL 19 & tools & extra options
as follow [image]

& make sure to add sdk url in environment variable

Answer (score 1):

New Android Studio has moved gradle wrapper to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper. I copied the templates\ folder to sdk\, then passed the compilation. However the command "Ionic emulate android" still failed with "Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1". I don't know how to go further :(